Why does Spring Security throw 401 unauthorized on permitted endpoint when another Exception in thrown (500 internal server error or 400 bad request)?
I am currently working on a uni project and experiencing a weird issue.
In the project we have a couple of endpoints that should not require authentication.
For the others we use HTTP Basic.
Now, while implementing the permitting logic I found out that on the permitted endpoints a 401 is returned whenever another error occurs, like a internal server error or a Bad request. Why is this? Am I doing something wrong? I took me 3+ hours to find out I was implementing Spring Security correctly (afaik), but was just using wrong requests (I thought that wouldn't matter)
here are some Code Snippets:
The Spring Security Config:
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                        // permit access without authentication to these endpoints:
                        .authorizeHttpRequests(permit -> permit.requestMatchers("/api/devices/update-status",
                                        "/api/device-models/register/{uuid}").permitAll())
                        // require authentication for any other request
                        .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize.anyRequest().authenticated())
                        // disable CSRF prevention
                        .csrf((csrf) -> csrf.disable())
                        // include HTTP Basic
                        .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults()).build();
    }
}

The HTTP Request:
PATCH localhost:8080/api/devices/update-status
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "uuid": "9b929ae8-1441-43df-be8f-0244c9b6ad38",
  "deviceUpdateState": "UP_TO_DATE",
  "version": "1",
  "updateLog": "x"
}

Since this Request is ok, it returns:
HTTP/1.1 200 
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 0
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Thu, 19 Dec 2024 18:22:27 GMT

{
  "uuid": "9b929ae8-1441-43df-be8f-0244c9b6ad38",
  "model": "model",
  "version": "1",
  "updateState": "UP_TO_DATE",
  "updateLog": "log",
  "wireguardIpV4Address": "0.11.0.1",
  "wireguardPublicKey": "key"
}

But if I change the Request so that it would return a 500 internal server error...
PATCH localhost:8080/api/devices/update-status
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "definetlynotuuid": "9b929ae8-1441-43df-be8f-0244c9b6ad38",
  "deviceUpdateState": "UP_TO_DATE",
  "version": "1",
  "updateLog": "x"
}

... it returns instead:
HTTP/1.1 401 
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 0
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Realm"
Content-Length: 0
Date: Thu, 19 Dec 2024 18:34:36 GMT

<Response body is empty>

Can anyone tell me why this happens? the endpoint requiring authorization work fine, and return the error code I expect (if the authorization succeded)
Thanks a lot in advance!
Funnily enough, if add the authorization to the false request, it works:
PATCH localhost:8080/api/devices/update-status
Host: localhost:8080
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Authorization: Basic ---credentials---
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "definetlynotuuid": "9b929ae8-1441-43df-be8f-0244c9b6ad38",
  "deviceUpdateState": "UP_TO_DATE",
  "version": "1",
  "updateLog": "x"
}

Response:
HTTP/1.1 500 
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 0
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Content-Language: en-US
Content-Length: 287
Date: Thu, 19 Dec 2024 18:36:49 GMT
Connection: close

<html>
<body><h1>Whitelabel Error Page</h1>
<p>This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.</p>
<div id='created'>Thu Dec 19 19:36:49 CET 2024</div>
<div>There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).</div>
</body>
</html>
Response file saved.

